# How to alter the intensity of a shadow cast by a three.js object?

Tags: three.js

How can I alter the intensity of a shadow cast by an object in the three.js? Currently translucent materials cast a shadow as intense as opaque objects. Obviously I'd like the translucent ones to not cast such an intense shadow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When casting shadows in three.js using `WebGLRenderer`, objects are treated as solid and non-translucent from the point of view of the light.

You can control the shadow intensity on a per-light basis by setting `light.shadowDarkness` to a value in the range [ 0, 1 ].

three.js r.64

---

EDIT: `light.shadowDarkness` is no longer supported as of three.js r.74. You can add ambient light to your scene to compensate.

three.js r.75

Comment: So I could create duplicate light and lower the light.shadowDarkness of one. Other than that I presume I'll have to create my own shaders (I'm trying to fully understand the three.js standard setup before going that route).

Comment: Just as an update, you cannot do this as of v74. You must use an ambient light to define the color of your shadows.

Comment: @Radio Updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Pravasith See this workaround: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14087#issuecomment-431003830.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

Create two point lights in the same location, one casts a shadow, the other doesn't. By making the shadow light dim, you can create a soft shadow.

Note in the example below, both lights are in position -100,200,200. The total intensity of the light from this location is 0.9, but the light which casts a shadow is only 0.2.

```
var shadowLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.2);
shadowLight.position.set(-100,200,100);
shadowLight.castShadow = true;
shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
shadowLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
scene.add(shadowLight);

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xfffff3, 0.7);
light.position.set(-100,200,100);
scene.add(light);
```